# Odd jQuery AJAX behaviour: XML comes back as #document and not object

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I have an issue with jQuery, where trying to fetch an XML document it comes back as `#document` in the console as opposed to an object I can act on. Why is this?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$.get('/ingredients/view_xml/' + ingredientId, function(xml) {
    console.log(xml);
}, 'xml');
```

And here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ingredient>
    <entryId>700</entryId>
    <title>GUINEA FOWL WHOLE FRESH X 1.5KG</title>
    <ingredientUnit>KG</ingredientUnit>
    <ingredientCost>5.03</ingredientCost>
</ingredient>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is a n00b mistake I've made and can't see right now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **dataType**
>   Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
>   If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the
>   MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in
>   1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will
>   execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a
>   string). The available types (and the result passed as the first
>   argument to your success callback) are:
>
> "xml": Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.
>   [...]

Further, the document is parsed using [jQuery.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) which is simply a wrapper around the browser's "native" XML parsing. The resulting document can be traversed and manipulated using the DOM, or, more conveniently, using jQuery. Example from doc:

```js
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $title = $xml.find( "title" );

/* append "RSS Title" to #someElement */
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because it is a document (it's parsed by [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) which returns a document if you have set the correct headers), if you want to use jQuery methods on it you should wrap it in jQuery

```
$.get('/ingredients/view_xml/' + ingredientId, function(xml) {
    console.log($(xml));
}, 'xml');
```